# Java webpage execute script

Tags: java, html, jsp

I am new to Java, please help.

I wrote html page index.jsp that suppose to get value from user and execute a script with that value.

The code is-

```html
<body>
    <form name="Execute-Java" action="">
            <p>
                <label for="s">IP- </label>
          <input type="text" name="server" value="x.x.x.x">
            </p><br>
      
            <input type="submit" value="Execute java" name="Submit"/>
    </form>
</body>
```

Also wrote a java code, compiled it using javac and ran it using java command-line successfully.

```
public class SendEmail {
  public static void main(String [] args){
  String from = "from@from.com";
  String to = "to@to.com";
  String subject = "Test Subject";
  String body_email = "Body test";
  String host = "x.x.x.x";

 //Get the session object
  Properties properties = System.getProperties();
  properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);
  Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

 //compose the message
  try{
     MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
     message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
     message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress(to));
     message.setSubject(subject);
     message.setText(body_email);

     // Send message
     Transport.send(message);
     System.out.println("message sent successfully....");

  }catch (MessagingException mex) {mex.printStackTrace();}
```

}
}

Now i would like the index.jsp page to somehow execute the java code when user click **submit** using the host value given by the user.

Can it be done and what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do some calculations with user input from html (jsp) on server-side you should use *Application-Layer protocol from OSI (HTTP, HTTPS f.e.)*.

Approach - using Ajax send http request to Server (java-servlet resource, deployed on **Tomcat** or another servlet container). Or you may use default behavior of **form.submit()**.

Make SendEmail class an Servlet extending it from HTTPServlet, implement doPost method(or doGet), set address for servlet.

Set action and method attributes for form.

Submit form.